# GCC Stack Clash Protection Not Emitted for a Function

Tags: c++, assembly, gcc, x86-64

Let's say we've got the following C++ code:

```
struct Base {
    int x[10000];
};

void foo(Base base) {}

int main() {
    Base base;
    foo(base);
}
```

GCC 11.4 [emitted assembly code](https://godbolt.org/z/Y3aT7Kc4s) (`-O0 -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection`):

```
foo(Base):
        endbr64
        pushq   %rbp
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        nop
        popq    %rbp
        ret
main:
        endbr64
        pushq   %rbp
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        leaq    -36864(%rsp), %r11
.LPSRL0:
        subq    $4096, %rsp
        orq     $0, (%rsp)
        cmpq    %r11, %rsp
        jne     .LPSRL0
        subq    $3152, %rsp
        movq    %fs:40, %rax
        movq    %rax, -8(%rbp)
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        subq    $40000, %rsp
        movq    %rsp, %rax
        movq    %rax, %rcx
        leaq    -40016(%rbp), %rax
        movl    $40000, %edx
        movq    %rax, %rsi
        movq    %rcx, %rdi
        call    memcpy
        call    foo(Base)
        addq    $40000, %rsp
        movl    $0, %eax
        movq    -8(%rbp), %rdx
        subq    %fs:40, %rdx
        je      .L4
        call    __stack_chk_fail
.L4:
        leave
        ret
```

The purpose of this part of the assembly code is ostensibly to prevent [stack clash](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Instrumentation-Options.html) style attacks, for which the compiler only allocates one page of stack space at a time and each page is accessed immediately after allocation (`or`). Thus, it prevents allocations from jumping over any stack guard page provided by the operating system:

```
       leaq    -36864(%rsp), %r11
.LPSRL0:
        subq    $4096, %rsp
        orq     $0, (%rsp)
        cmpq    %r11, %rsp
        jne     .LPSRL0
```

The following part of the code seems to be responsible for the preparation for and the subsequent calling of `foo()`;

```
        subq    $40000, %rsp
        movq    %rsp, %rax
        movq    %rax, %rcx
        leaq    -40016(%rbp), %rax
        movl    $40000, %edx
        movq    %rax, %rsi
        movq    %rcx, %rdi
        call    memcpy
        call    foo(Base)
```

Notice, that the compiler apparently no longer applies its stack clash protection here. Is this by design?

Thanks.

Comment: `memcpy` touches all the bytes (in some order).  If there's a problem, it will definitely crash.  Maybe after overwriting something, but it will crash.

Comment: I'm not an expert, but in the examples that I've seen, the check for stack frame corruption always happen at the very end of a function (the `__stack_chk_fail` call here), right before the function is about to return - not before any subroutine calls. Overwriting the current stack frame does not really affect how subroutines behave but it _will_ obviously affect where the current routine returns to, unless it's detected.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError: That's "stack *smashing*", a different issue: it checks for the possibility that buggy code wrote outside the bounds of a local buffer, going beyond its stack frame and overwriting the return address etc.  Here we are talking about "stack *clash*", where allocating a large local object jumped the stack pointer so far that it ended up pointing to unrelated memory.  This would cause problems even for 100% correct source code that never writes outside of its proper stack frame.  The issue here is that the stack frame *itself* is in a bad location.

Comment: @NateEldredge: Aha, thanks - learn something new every day.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Sometimes, several things

Comment: UB here, strictly speaking, because you don't initialise `x` but you do then copy it.  But I don't think it's affecting anything.  Also, making `sizeof (x)` (in bytes) a multiple of 4096 simplifies the generated assembly slightly, making it easier to eyeball.  Good question though, the reason why the generated code is as it is is not obvious.